# derivative of sum of singular values

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis

can someone point me to the direction how to calculate the derivatives of a sum of singular values of a matrix?
I am trying to minimize
$$\min_A \parallel A \parallel_*+ \cdots $$ where $\parallel A \parallel_*=\sum_i \sigma_i$ is the sum of the singular values of $A$.

This is motivated by this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3704-robust-principal-component-analysis-exact-recovery-of-corrupted-low-rank-matrices-via-convex-optimization.pdf).

Thank you very much!

**Update**:
Here is the full problem:
$$\min_A \parallel A \parallel_* + \lambda  \parallel \nabla_A \parallel D-A-E\parallel_F^2  \parallel_F^2$$
with targeted decomposition $D=A+E$

The authors of the mentioned paper use the so called "singular value thresholding" to solve it:

$$u,s,v=SVD(A-\frac{1}{2}(A+E-D))$$
after setting $S=$diag($(s_i-\tau)_+$)
$$A_{k+1}=u\cdot S \cdot v^T$$

However, I dont see how to get there. :(

Comment: Are you sure you need the derivative? The minimum is obviously $-\infty$, unless you have constraints. It may be easier to help you if you state the problem in full.

Comment: @Alex singular values are constrained to be nonnegative, so the minimum is $0$.

Comment: Look at page 5 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3286 -- this paper uses the subdifferential theorems of A. Lewis to derive the thresholding operator. A simpler derivation of all of this can also be obtained: to do that see the *Moreau decomposition*, as discussed e.g., in: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1437

Comment: Thanks to all of you! 
I found Suvrit's answers best for my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is not differentiable (consider $A=0$). If you are interested in learning about its subdifferential (and more on subdifferential of spectral functions), please refer to the excellent papers:

1. [A. Lewis. *Nonsmooth analysis of singular values: Part I*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11228-004-7197-7)
2. [A. Lewis. *Nonsmooth analysis of singular values: Part II*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11228-004-7198-6)